# Parsing user-typed Full Text Search queries

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have a search string and I want parse and convert it into MySQL query. For example:

```
(tag:"marketing" || tag:seo) && "example@example.com" && test
```

to

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   `table` 
WHERE 
   (`tag` LIKE "%marketing%" OR `tag` LIKE "%seo%") AND 
   content LIKE "%example@example.com%" AND 
   content LIKE "%test%"
```

P.S. I've already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185244/parsing-user-typed-full-text-search-queries-into-where-clause-of-mysql-using-php) and [this](https://github.com/gdbots/query-parser-php), but these solutions are not for me. Maybe somebody knows popular one?

Comment: Including "this" type links can lead to problems; forums are littered with broken links that leave the original problem opaque. Can you flesh out what you have tried, esp with an examples?

Comment: @CharlieJoynt [Package](https://github.com/gdbots/query-parser-php) works with errors: incorrect parse search string into subqueries