# How to parse custom user search request into full-text search?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, lucene, full-text-search

At the moment I am using a simple full-text search with against/match of full phrase typed by the user. The idea is to allow user type a search request using the following connectors:

```
AND, OR, NOT
"" - exact match
() - grouping terms
* - single letter wildcard
! - root expander
/n - terms within n words of each other
/s - terms within same sentence of each other
/p - terms within the same paragraph
```

All these connectors will work as boolean operators. The task contains two parts:
1. to parse the string typed by the user (with the possible syntax errors)
2. build the SQL query

The exact same search works here - https://casetext.com/search

Also, I'm wondering if it will be easier to move to Lucena/Solr or Elasticsearch which have build-in parsers but still not the same what I need?

I saw already this [parsing user-typed Full Text Search queries into WHERE clause of MySQL using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185244/parsing-user-typed-full-text-search-queries-into-where-clause-of-mysql-using-php) but it's not giving any answers

And I saw these packages:
https://packagist.org/packages/pecee/boolean-query-parser - basic syntax supported
https://packagist.org/packages/gdbots/query-parser - more sophisticated but not covering last 4 connectors from my list

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Are you using MySQL's FULLTEXT search in Boolean mode? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html  That offers a bit of a search language. Is your task to translate your search language into that one?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the post. The thing is that the user can make a mistake in his search string request. And the parser should be able to deal with that also.