# Validating the input for a SQL Server Full Text Search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, validation

From my web app I want to give the user the full power of CONTAINS in a full text search however it's very easy for a user to enter an invalid string such as a phrase that's not in quotes.

I could laboriously parse the input and work out whether it's valid or I could handle the syntax error that comes back from SQL.

But are these the only two options? Is there anything I can use to validate the input?

Comment: not sure if MsSql supports it, but can't you use prepared statements?

Comment: @Daan I believe they are the equivalent of parameterized queries which I am already using.

Comment: Well, if they indeed are the same, then there is no problem submitting user-input directly in to the database using a prepared/parameterized statement. Just be 100% sure that the SQL is first parsed and only then that your data/input is supplied.

Comment: My question was more to do with the blind creation of errors as opposed to validating the input first. Trying to avoid SQL insertion by using parameterized queries/prepared statements is a different matter I believe.

Comment: +1 Chris, did you ever resolve this? If so, how?

Comment: Hi @Dommer, I'm afraid not. I resorted to a small amount of pre-parsing to capture the most common issues and left the rest to SQL. I've since moved on to other projects. Good luck with whatever you're on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting user-entered search query to where clause for use in SQL Server full-text search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506034/converting-user-entered-search-query-to-where-clause-for-use-in-sql-server-full)