# SQL Server Full-Text Search Issue: Inconsistent Results Between CONTAINS and LIKE Queries with word 'za'

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-like, contains, full-text-catalog

For the first time, I'm using full-text search. I have SQL Server 2022 Standard installed, and I've set up full-text search. I created a full-text catalog, `[fullTextCatalog_CjeniciArtikli]`, with `ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF`.

I have a table named `CjeniciArtikli` with a column, `Naziv`, which I've created a full-text index for. The language is set to Croatian, and `accent_sensitive` is set to false.

When I execute the query below, it doesn't return any results, although it should:

```
SELECT *
FROM CjeniciArtikli
WHERE CONTAINS(Naziv, 'orink AND tinta AND za AND canon');
```

However, when I use the `LIKE` operator with a similar query, it returns 64 records, which is correct:

```
SELECT *
FROM CjeniciArtikli
WHERE Naziv LIKE '%orink%' AND Naziv LIKE '%tinta%' AND Naziv LIKE '%za%' AND Naziv LIKE '%canon%';
```

If I modify the first query by removing the word 'za', it returns the records as expected (just like when using LIKE), even though some of those records contain the word 'za'. For example, the first result returned is

```
Orink tinta za Canon, CLI-521GY, siva, OR-CCLI521G with chi
```

which contains word 'za'.

```
SELECT *
FROM CjeniciArtikli
WHERE CONTAINS(Naziv, 'orink AND tinta AND canon'); --works
```

When I tried searching for just the word 'za', it didn't return any results:

```
SELECT *
FROM CjeniciArtikli
WHERE CONTAINS(Naziv, 'za');
```

However, when I used LIKE, it returned 5,877 records:

```
SELECT *
FROM CjeniciArtikli
WHERE Naziv LIKE '% za %';
```

I initially thought the issue might be due to two-letter words, but when I tested a query with the word 'sa', it worked without any problems.

I haven't been able to find a solution on the internet or through AI language models, including ChatGPT.

If anyone knows what might be causing this issue, I would greatly appreciate any assistance. I've tried several resources, but without success.

Comment: Full text indexes don't use and/or, you should read about the query syntax

Comment: how it doesnt use AND/OR when it is in official documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Could it be that `za` is in a STOPLIST? See: [Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some insight into this from running

```
DECLARE @system_stoplist_id INT = 0;

DECLARE @lcid INT = (SELECT lcid
   FROM   sys.syslanguages
   WHERE  alias = 'Croatian');

SELECT *
FROM   sys.dm_fts_parser ('orink AND tinta AND za AND canon', @lcid, @system_stoplist_id, 0)
```

This returns

| keyword | group_id | phrase_id | occurrence | special_term | display_term | expansion_type | source_term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x006F00720069006E006B | 1 | 0 | 1 | Exact Match | orink | 0 | orink |
| 0x00740069006E00740061 | 2 | 0 | 1 | Exact Match | tinta | 0 | tinta |
| 0x007A0061 | 3 | 0 | 1 | **Noise Word** | za | 0 | za |
| 0x00630061006E006F006E | 4 | 0 | 1 | Exact Match | canon | 0 | canon |

So by default "za" is treated as a stop word because it is so common (in Croatian).

If you need this not to be treated as a stop word then you will need to [customise the stop words used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) rather than just accepting the system default list.

TBH I find it somewhat surprising that a `CONTAINS` query with `AND stop_word` would cause it to return no results rather than just have that component ignored but I can repro this behaviour too.

I guess it does make sense because for every row it is "Unknown" whether or not "za" exists in the value and [`TRUE AND UNKNOWN` is `UNKNOWN` - not `TRUE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Kleene_and_Priest_logics)

The `CONTAINS` query does at least print out

> Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s).

to the messages tab to somewhat alert you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. That is really weird because the word 'sa' is more common, but it is working. What would be the easiest solution to ignore the word 'za' so my query works?

Comment: @Mladen - I guess create your own stop word list rather than using the system default. You can do `SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords WHERE language_id = 1050` to see what the system default words are for Croatian and see what you want to keep out of that for your custom one

Comment: Looks like you would need to do `ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX  ... SET STOPLIST` to use the new list but I haven't worked with full text search for > 10 years so not something I have particular knowledge on

Comment: @Mladen - Looks like there is another option too - if you just want the stop words in the query to be silently ignored https://stackoverflow.com/a/10451332/73226 - but this seems less good because it will then potentially bring back rows that don't contain `za`

Comment: And actually I just tried the `transform noise words` option and it didn't make any difference for me - even after rebuilding the full text catalog and deleting and recreating the full text index

Comment: that solved my problem exactly i wanted to be :))))